# Regular Expression for retrieving File Extension in HTTP url

Tags: regex

I am working on the ELK stack and as part of Logstash data transformation i am transforming data in Apache access logs.

One of the metric needed is to get a stat on different content types (aspx, php, gif, etc.).

From the log file I am trying to retrieve request url and then deduce the file type, for ex `/c/dataservices/online.jsp?callBack` is the request and I would get `.aspx` using the regular expression 
`\.\w{3,4}`.

My regular expression wont work for request say `/etc/designs/design/libs.min.1253.css` this is returning me `.min` as the extension.

I am trying to get the last extension but it is not working. Please do suggest other approaches.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to anchor the match to the end of the string or the beginning of a query param `?`. Try:

```
\.\w{3,4}($|\?)
```

Play with it here: https://regex101.com/r/iV3iM1/1

Comment: (\.\w{3,4})($|\?) get group 1 for ignore '?'

Comment: The last `($|\?)` produces an empty capture group. You could probably do `(?:$|\?)` on that one to not capture whatever comes after the extension. Also, to capture only the actual file extension (and not the leading dot) : `\.(\w{3,4})(?:$|\?)`

Comment: Yep, this is a good suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

You're going to need a much fancier Regex.

Try this one.

```
([/.\w]+)([.][\w]+)([?][\w./=]+)?
```

This uses three capture groups.  The first `([/.\w]+)` matches your path up to the last `.`

The second `([.][\w]+)` matches the final extension, and you can use the capture group to read it out.

The third `([?][\w./=]+)?` matches the query string, which is optional.

Comment: This doesn't work. Just so you're aware - https://regexr.com/6vl2o

Comment: The reason this does not work is that the initial capture group is too restrictive.  There are many characters allowed in a URL that it would not capture, so this breaks.  It worked for the OP's example, but it's easy to make one where it won't.  The accepted answer is better.